Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refs') in React Js using NX monorepo
Getting this error while closing the modal from closeModal component. I have written path replace  using history.push() function.
Ex.
const OnClose = () =>{
     history.push({
  pathname: "/dashboard"
})
}

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refs')
        at detach (chunk-Q6I74RLG.js?v=00eb7286:3078:3)
        at chunk-Q6I74RLG.js?v=00eb7286:3150:9
        at chunk-Q6I74RLG.js?v=00eb7286:3105:9
        at safelyCallDestroy (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:16748:13)
        at commitHookEffectListUnmount (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:16875:19)
        at commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:18232:17)
        at commitPassiveUnmountEffects_complete (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:18213:15)
        at commitPassiveUnmountEffects_begin (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:18204:15)
        at commitPassiveUnmountEffects (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:18169:11)
        at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:19489:11)
        at flushPassiveEffects (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:19447:22)
        at performSyncWorkOnRoot (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:18868:11)
        at flushSyncCallbacks (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:9119:30)
        at commitRootImpl (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:19432:11)
        at commitRoot (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:19277:13)
        at finishConcurrentRender (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=00eb7286:18805:15)
    
    **The above error occurred in the <CloseModal> component.**

enter image description here

please add all the pieces of code that you consider relevant to know the context around this feature (the component(s) involved, for example)

Can you provide local version of the error as the above minified version is not clear for anyone to help you debug your error? Additionaly you could check for if(history && history.push) before pushing object to it if thats the issue. or else you will have to share the error message from your local run of the application

Added the screenshot for the same.

What is at the third and first images?
